# Can't change user password for Django user model using ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-permissions, django-auth-models, django-viewsets

I was using Django user model using the ModelViewSet. When I am making a request to update the password for the current user that is logged in. Although I get a 200 OK response but my password never changes to the new one that I changed.

I also tried making the request from my admin user and when I made the PUT request with the password, it got changed to something else and I was logged out from the django admin panel.

Here is my

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOfObject]
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {
                'write_only':True,
                'required': True
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user) # create token for the user
        return user
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('articles', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename = 'users')


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**permissions.py**

```
class IsOwnerOfObject(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user
```

Here is how I am making the request, with Authorisation token in the Headers field

[image]

Response :

[image]

Comment: I think you will have to override `update` to be able to call `set_password` for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BrianDestura says, you need call `set_password` to correctly update it.

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # --> Add this method
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # We Can change the username?
        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: but I thought using `ModelViewSet` already takes care of PUT method

Comment: I'm not sure, but the `ModelViewset` maybe save the raw database password, not the encrypted one.

Comment: this does not update my token based on the new password